# Table design for storing multiple ranges in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database-design, range

I have several categories that I need to store in a database and present them to users. Each one has a minimum of three to a maximum of four ranges. E.g.:

```
id | category_name | Range A |  Range B  |  Range C  |  Range D  
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | Category1     | 0 - 200 | 200 - 450 | 450 - 750 | 750+
 2 | Category2     | 0 - 300 | 300 - 600 | 600+      |           
 3 | Category3     | 0 - 250 | 250 - 350 | 350 - 550 | 550+
```

When an user picks a category, he should then select a certain range that will be saved in the database.

```
    name    | category_id | category_range
------------------------------------------
 niceuser30 | 2           | A
 hellouser1 | 1           | B
```

Considering that:

- ranges **cannot have gaps** between them (e.g. if range A goes from 100 to 200, range B **must** start from 200)
- each range must start from 0
- each range must be open ended (or half-open)

What would be the best design for a table to hold these values?

I was thinking of using something akin to this

```
id | category_name | range_a | range_b | range_c | range_d
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Category1     | 1500    | 3000    | 5000    | 5000
2  | Category2     | 500     | 1000    | 1000    |
```

and then elaborate the output before serving it to the user (if two ranges are equal the code sets the last one "ad infinitum", so the first one would be "0 - 1500, 1500 - 3000, 3000 - 5000, 5000+") but it seems *dirty* and prone to errors.

Comment: This cannot be answered adequately without knowing what queries will be applied to the table.

Answer (score 0):

you could use 2  table e.g `Ranges:`

```
   id  | RangeName| Start |  End |  Range  | 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 | A        | 0    | 1500 | 1500     |
     2 | B        | 1500 | 3000 | 1500     |           
     3 | C        | 3000 | 4000 | 1000     | 
     ....
```

and `RangeCategories`:

```
  id   | CategoryID|RangeId| 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 | 1         |   1   | 
     2 | 1         |   2   |          
     3 | 2         |   3   | 
     4 | 2         |   1   | 
     .....
```

And of course you will also have your `categories` Table:

```
    id | CategoryName|...
   --------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 | Category1     | ...
     2 | Category2     | ...          
     3 | Category3     | ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, ranges aren't always fixed (e.g. I can't have a start/end as 0/1500 with a range of 1500, because the next range could be from 1500 to 2500).